# Nodemailer Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN" - OR - Error Error: Mail command failed: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required. Env variable issue

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemailer

I am really struggling with Nodemailer using Gmail in my NodeJS backend application. I have tried both OAuth and 2 factor authentication but am getting the following errors:
Either

`Error Error: Mail command failed: 530-5.7.0 Authentication Required.`

OR

`Nodemailer Error: Missing credentials for "PLAIN"`

Nodemailer set up is as below with OAuth when I am receiving the Authentication required error:

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

interface mailOptions {
  from: string;
  to: string;
  subject: string;
  html: string;
}

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: "smtp.gmail.com",
  service: "gmail",
  port: "587",
  secure: false,
  auth: {
    type: "OAuth2",
    user: 'EMAIL',
    pass: 'EMAIL PASSWORD',
    clientId: 'CLIENTID',
    clientSecret: 'CLIENT SECRET',
    refreshToken: 'OAUTH REFRESH TOKEN',
  },
});

transporter.verify((err, success) => {
  err
    ? console.log(err)
    : console.log(`=== Server is ready to take messages: ${success} ===`);
});

export const sendMail = (mailOptions: mailOptions) =>
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error " + err);
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent successfully");
    }
  });
```

The Missing credentials for "PLAIN" error is set up as below using 2 factor authentication:

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";

interface mailOptions {
  from: string;
  to: string;
  subject: string;
  html: string;
}

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: 'EMAIL',
    pass: '2 FACTOR GENERATED PASSWORD FOR THE APP',
  },
});

transporter.verify((err, success) => {
  err
    ? console.log(err)
    : console.log(`=== Server is ready to take messages: ${success} ===`);
});

export const sendMail = (mailOptions: mailOptions) =>
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error " + err);
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent successfully");
    }
  });
```

controller code is as such:

```
  ForgotPassword: async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    try {
      const user = await userSchema.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
      const username = user?.username;

      if (user) {
        const secret = process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN + user.password;
        const payload = {
          email: user.email,
          id: user._id,
        };
        const token = jwt.sign(payload, secret, { expiresIn: "15m" });
        const link = `http://localhost:${process.env.PORT}/user/reset-password/${user._id}/${token}`;

        // console.log(link, token);

        // Add in logic for sending the link via email to user here

        const mailOptions = {
          from: 'EMAIL',
          to: 'EMAIL',
          subject: "Password Reset",
          html: "HTML",
        };

        sendMail(mailOptions);

        res.status(200).send("Password reset link has been sent to your email");
      } else {
        res.status(404).send("User not found!");
      }
    } catch (e: unknown) {}
  },
```

Edit:
The issue appears to be with loading environment variables, I added the email and generated password for 2 step verification into my app and it works perfectly. How to I get this to work with env variables?

Answer (score 0):

After posting the edit, I ended up thinking that maybe I need to enable dotenv in my service file for the nodemailer. This worked perfectly. The following is the code I now have.

```
import nodemailer from "nodemailer";
import * as dotenv from "dotenv";
dotenv.config();

interface mailOptions {
  from: string;
  to: string;
  subject: string;
  html: string;
}

const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: "gmail",
  auth: {
    user: 'EMAIL',
    pass: '2 FACTOR GENERATED PASSWORD FOR THE APP',
  },
});

transporter.verify((err, success) => {
  err
    ? console.log(err)
    : console.log(`=== Server is ready to take messages: ${success} ===`);
});

export const sendMail = (mailOptions: mailOptions) =>
  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Error " + err);
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent successfully");
    }
  });
```